# binary '+=': no global operator found when trying to add a object to an array of objects

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to add a Complex number, represented in **Complex class** to an array of complex.

```
 #pragma once

    class Complex
    {

    private:
        int re, im;

public:
    Complex() {};
    Complex(int a, int b) { re = a; im = b; }
    Complex(const Complex &);
    Complex& operator=(const Complex &);

    //operators overloading
    bool operator==(Complex);

    //member function
    void print();
};

class Multime
{
private: 
    Complex *array;
    static int nrElem;
    int dim;

public:
    Multime();
    Multime(int a) { dim = a; nrElem = 0; array = new Complex[dim]; }
    ~Multime();

    //Operators overloading
    Multime& operator += (Complex b);
    Multime& operator =(const Multime &);

    //member function
    void print();
};
```

**Functions.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Multime.h"

using namespace std;

Complex::Complex(const Complex &a)
{
    re = a.re;
    im = a.im;
}

Complex& Complex::operator= (const Complex&a)
{
    re = a.re;
    im = a.im;
    return *this;
}

void Complex::print()
{
    cout << re << "+" << im << "i" << endl;
}

bool Complex::operator==(const Complex a)
{
    return (re == a.re && im == a.im);
}
//Multime
//

Multime::Multime()
{
    dim = 0;
    nrElem = 0;
    array = nullptr;
}

Multime::~Multime()
{
    if (nullptr != array)
    {
        delete[] array;
    }
}

void Multime::print()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nrElem; ++i)
    {
        array[i].print();
    }
    cout << endl;
}

Multime& Multime::operator +=(Complex a)
{
    int g = 0;
    if (nrElem < dim)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nrElem; ++i)
        {
            if (array[i] == a)
            {
                g = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!g) //Element not found, can insert
    {
        array[nrElem++] = a;
    }
    return *this;
}

Multime& Multime::operator =(const Multime & a)
{
    dim = a.dim;
    array = new Complex[dim];
    for (int i = 0; i < nrElem; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = a.array[i];
    }
    return *this;
}
```

In main I wrote the initialization for the static **int Multime::nrElem = 0;** after preprocessor directivesand and in main(void):

```
Multime a[50];
    Complex f(2, 5), b(1, 3), c(5, 4);
    a+=f;
```

but I get the error: binary '+=': no global operator found.I don't wanna use a friend function for +. I tried to create separate functions for + and = but the error is still there.

***LE. The problem was in main* a** it's an array of Multime. Correct one, using initialization constructor: **Multime a(50);**

Comment: `a` is an array of `Multime`...

Comment: You're right. Sorry for that. It's working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a+=f;
```

is not valid since `a` is an array of `Multime`, not an object of type `Multime`.

If you want to use the `operator+=` on one object, you could use

```
a[0] += f;
```

If you want to use it for all the objects in the array, use a loop.

```
for ( auto& item : a )
{
   item += f;
}
```